# Dynamically allocating contiguous 2-d array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I want to allocate **contiguous memory** for 2-d array **dynamically**, and I reached up to this page:- https://dev.to/drakargx/c-contiguous-allocation-of-2-d-arrays-446m

I didn't understand this person's code inside the loop:-

```
for(int i = 1; i < num_rows; i++) {
  matrix[i] = matrix[i-1] + num_cols;
}
```

How the address of all the elements are going to be **contiguous**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> How the address of all the elements are going to be **contiguous**?

All *the elements* (which are one-dimensional arrays, rows) are contiguous due to the immediately preceding statement under [A better, less intuitive way of creating 2-dimensional arrays dynamically](https://dev.to/drakargx/c-contiguous-allocation-of-2-d-arrays-446m#a-better-less-intuitive-way-of-creating-2dimensional-arrays-dynamically) which you didn't show:

```
matrix[0] = new int[num_rows * num_cols];
```

Here the whole matrix is allocated by one `new`, naturally contiguous.